# how do i run a container so that it is running behind a proxy + on running?

Tags: proxy, docker, containers

how do i run a container so that it is running behind a proxy?

currently I have to run my image/container:
`docker run -it <imagename>`

then I have to do the following:

```
export http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128
export https_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128
```

Is there a way I can put the proxy in a file in the image and then commit and then every time I start it I do not have to issue the export command to point at the proxies?

i have tried putting my proxy settings:

```
export http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128
export https_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128
```

in the following files:

`/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment`

and then commited this new image. But then when I run this image with:

`docker run -it <imagename>`

and I do a `env | grep proxy` my proxy settings are not in the `env` but they are present in the file.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env) command in your dockerfile...

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env

Comment: tks got taht to work doing as follows `docker run --env http_proxy=http://10.201.202.49:53128 --rm -i -t -p 3000:3000 meteor-todos:0.1` but i was hoping to store it in the image/container, in a file or the like. And not have to setit up when I call the image. can this be done?

Comment: maybe if i run this container `docker run --env http_proxy=http://10.201.202.49:53128 --rm -i -t -p 3000:3000 meteor-todos:0.1` and then commit it as an image it will hold the environment variables?

Comment: for my reference: I can restart the container that I exited and the env variable will still be there `docker start -ai <container_name>
`

Comment: for my reference: I can commit the container as an image `docker commit -a "name &lt;email#email.com&gt;" -m "meteor added proxy using --env" 2628 meteor-todos:0.2`  and then run that image and the env variable will still be there `docker run --rm -it meteor-todos:0.2
`